# how to set a comboBox's style inside a WPF DataGrid?

Tags: wpf, xaml, datagrid, styles

I have a DataGrid containing some DataGridComboBoxColumns.

I would like the comboBoxes inside those columns to have a certain style applied.

so I tried adding the following to my DataGrid's Resources:

```
<Style x:Key="{x:Type ComboBox}" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true"/>
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true"/>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="true"/>

    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource DefaultBackgroundBrush}"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource DefaultBorderBrush}"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource DefaultForegroundBrush}"/>
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{StaticResource DefaultFontFamily}"/>
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{StaticResource DefaultFontSize}"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="2"/>
</Style>
```

does not do anything at all.

amazingly enough, if I add:

```
<Style x:Key="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}" TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true"/>
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
</Style>
```

the comboBoxItems inside the same comboBoxes will get the red foreground color Correctly.

so basically, I cannot set the style of the comboBoxes inside my dataGrid, but I can set the style of the comboBoxItems inside those same comboBoxes.

quite surprising...

does anyone have a clue about what's going on here and how I can solve my problem?

thanks

Comment: I think defining an x:key=type is for situations when introducing new named styles. They are derived from the original style. But when making basedon={staticresource {x:type type}} it will use your default style i.e. the one with x:key={x:type type}  instead of the one provided by wpf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What exactly is this supposed to do? `x:Key="{x:Type ComboBox}"`

You should not assign keys if you want styles to be applied to all controls in the subtree.

**Edit:** To apply the styles to the ComboBoxes you must adjust the properties `DataGridComboBoxCotlumn.ElementStyle` and `DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle`.

Comment: see there: http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/ms752094%28v=VS.85%29.aspx  I'm not sure what it means, but I thought it did what you wrote, i.e.: sets the given style to all controls of the type given in the key parameter... If someone can explain, I'd love it (this way of doing things works generally speaking for all controls except the above mentioned comboBox (and I did not check but I'm willing to bet there is the same issue with checkbox columns)

Comment: In styles the x:Key is set implicitly to overwrite the control's resource dictionary key, so adding that should not change anything (at best it will screw it up if you have a spelling error in it). Read up on it here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/ms745683%28v=VS.85%29.aspx#styling_targettype

Comment: Updated answer with a relevant addition.

Comment: Ok, the second suggestion of using "EdintingElementStyle" works fine, thanks.... I'd still like to know why this damn style with the x:Key="{x:Type ComboBox}" set correctly did not work though... I'm now suspecting that comboBoxes inside dataGridCells aren't really comboBoxes, but rather controls of some other hidden Type, like DataGridComboBoxCell or something...

Comment: I suspect those properties i mentioned just override other styles that were specified at a higher level.