# What does x:Key="{x:Type TextBox}" do?

Tags: wpf, xaml, syntax

Everything is in the title:

I've read more than once that setting a style like this:

```
<Style TargetType="TextBox">...</Style>
```

was roughly equivalent to:

```
<Style x:Key="{x:Type TextBox}" TargetType="TextBox">...</Style>
```

(last time [in a comment on another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4853272/how-to-set-a-comboboxs-style-inside-a-wpf-datagrid/4853416#4853416))

both should apply the style to all textBoxes in the app (if they are put in the app's resources of course)

but I tried both in my apps, and only the second one with the x:Key defined works.

it seams quite logical for me, since the first one does not know where to be applied without any x:Key property set, but then what is the point of the first syntax?

**Edit:** example of code in my app that works fine:

```
<Style x:Key="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">
     <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"/>
     <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
</Style>
```

and code that doesn't:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">
     <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"/>
     <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
</Style>
```

I wrote this to get rid of the binding issues you get with comboBoxItems when you manipulate an existing ComboBox's itemsSource. And the first code works fine, but the second one does not.

you can see this easily by setting the horizontalContentAlignment to Right

**Edit 2:** This code is simply put in a resource dictionary in my App.xaml. And replacing TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}" with TargetType="ComboBoxItem" makes no difference whatsoever

**Edit 3:** I just realized I might have forgotten to precise something important (sorry about that): though the styles are defined in xaml, I actually add the controls to the layout in my code behind as they are added dynamically. Might be where the trouble lies...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> As shown in the first example above,
> setting the TargetType property to
> TextBlock without assigning the style
> with an x:Key allows your style to be
> applied to all TextBlock elements.
> What actually happens is that doing so
> implicitly sets the x:Key to {x:Type
> TextBlock}. This also means that if
> you give the Style an x:Key value of
> anything other than {x:Type
> TextBlock}, the Style would not be
> applied to all TextBlock elements
> automatically. Instead, you need to
> apply the style to the TextBlock
> elements explicitly.

Considering that this is [from the official documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745683%28v=VS.85%29.aspx#styling_targettype), your issue has to be an anomaly. I have seen a few such oddities and they are not all too unexpected since the coding behind WPF is bound to be imperfect.

(Is there a difference in outcomes between `TargetType="ComboBoxItem"` and `TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}"` if the key is omitted?)

Comment: Can you elaborate what you mean here: *since the coding behind WPF is bound to be imperfect.* Do you think this case is a bug in WPF? I think we need to see a lot more code before we can come to that conclusion.

Comment: "Do you think this case is a bug in WPF?" Yes, that is exactly what i mean. I don't think you need more code to come to that conclusion because we have a description of what *should* happen and a report that this is in fact not always the case. The provided code seems quite simple and if everything else is left completely the same you can conclude that the fault has to be with a core WPF code.

Comment: So what this is saying is you could combine the TargetType property with an x:Type property. Then your ComboBoxItem style will only apply when explicitly sit in the XAML.

Comment: I'm marking this as the right answer, since I am now convinced in has to be something like this. I indeed made a new test project just to try everything you guys wrote, and basically you're all right: I get exactly what you wrote I was supposed to get. Now, I am positive that this does not work in my main project as it does in my test project. There must be something somewhere that triggers a "wrong" behaviour, but I cannot find what. And this has nothing do to with the way my styles are declared, since I declared them in my test app exactly as they are declared in my main app.

Comment: Is there a difference in outcomes between `TargetType="ComboBoxItem"` and `TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}"` if the key is omitted?

Comment: @RuiMonteiro: There shouldn't be, as the property's type is `Type`, the conversion should happen automatically without using `{x:Type}`.

Answer (score 5):

Now you can cascade your styles by adding a:

```
BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ComboBox}}"
```

in a <Style/> further down the document, for example:

```
<Window.Resources>
     <Style x:Key="{x:Type TextBox}" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
          <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"/>
          <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
      </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<StackPanel>
    <TextBox>I'm Left-Center</TextBox>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.Resources>
           <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBox}}">
                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Right"/>
            </Style>
        <Grid.Resources>
        <TextBox>I'm Right-Center</TextBox>
    </Grid>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: did not know this syntax, interesting! does not really tell what the x:key="{x:type xxx}" does, though.

Comment: Your example works without the x:Key, so not really relevant here

Comment: Why not `TargetType="TextBox"` instead?

Answer (score 3):

Each resource needs a key, but if `Key` is omitted for a style, it should default to the type of the `TargetType`. So both of your snippets above should be equivalent.

Can you post the entire code where it does not work without the explicit `Key` definition?

Comment: Also, in your non-working example, try replacing TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem} with TargetType="ComboBoxItem"

Comment: I edited my question again with the answers to your questions: I am really puzzled by this. Maybe some other part of my app's code messes up with the way wpf behaves, but I'm not going to inspect every single comboBox I add though, would take too long and I can live with the x:Key set... It's really just out of curiosity...

Comment: I see your edit 3, and I would think that this is the reason in some way. But that does *not* explain why it's working when you explixitly set x:Key. Maybe the implicit key is something that the XAML parser takes care of, and don't apply to the programmatically added controls, while the explicit Key definition does, but that is only speculations from my end. An interesting case!

Answer (score 0):

In WPF XAML, both `TargetType="TextBox"` and `TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}"` are valid and equivalent.

The `x:Type` markup extension is used to specify a value of the `Type` object. In this case, it is specifying the type `TextBox`. It is commonly used in XAML to specify the type of a control, such as in the `TargetType` property of a style or data trigger.

Using `TargetType="TextBox"` is a shortcut that WPF provides to simplify the markup for the most commonly used scenarios. This syntax implicitly creates a `TypeExtension` for the `TextBox` type.

So both `TargetType="TextBox"` and `TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}"` will have the same result, which is to specify the `TextBox` type as the target type for the style or data trigger.